# Format script for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I want a script that can take all cells (a.k.a the entire spreadsheet) and put the text of the cell in a pattern format, so the font and size need to be same for all text, the horizontal align, vertical align, text wrapping, text color as well.

I saw this code on another stack overflow answer:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());

range.setNumberFormat("$#,##0.00;$(#,##0.00)");
```

But i this don't solve my problem.

Comment: Explain what you mean by `this doesn't solve my problem`. What are you getting with that and what is the expected output?

Comment: well, the code above only set the number format with a money sign, i want a code that can change all format, basically i want a code that the output is all cells in the same pattern of  font, size, horizontal align, vertical align, text wrapping and text color, independent if is a cell with numbers or text.

Comment: Does this format have a specific "font, size, align, color, etc?" If so, make use of the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) methods to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the script to apply formatting like you might manually apply, at least for me, was to open a spreadsheet, select TOOLS | MACROS and then do all the things you wanted done. For example set text size, font, alignment, and even FORMAT | ALTERNATING COLORS. Stop the macro recording and open it in the script editor. Take the code and add it to your main script. You can then delete the macro.